# How to enable httprequest for mamp 2.0 Mac mountain lion, not http_request2

Tags: php, httprequest

I installed `Http_Request2` and worked using it in my mac but my problem is, I need to upload this to my client's server.

It didn't work there because it doesn't have `Http_Request2` and they don't want to install it.

They said I should use the old `httprequest` that is included to mamp 2.0's php, but I'm having `httprequest class not found` error.

I searched the net and the php manual but it doesn't work, those are for windows.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but you may want to consider re-writing your code using CURL. CURL is everywhere so you don't have to worry about a server having it. Http_Request2 is just a wrapper for CURL.

Comment: @Michael Dela Pena hey how did you get http_request2 working on mamp? I'm having trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about problem with MAMP. MAMP by default is installed without httprequest library. You need to install it manually like you did it with your local server.

If your client doesn't want install any libraries from PECL you need to solve problem alternatively.